# Error in CRM Plugin - Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.3.2 Service not active

Tags: c#, .net, dynamics-crm-2011, crm, xrm

I have a CRM Plugin that's been working for a while now but recently started throwing the following error intermittently:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault, Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.3.2 Service not activeDetail: 
<OrganizationServiceFault xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xrm/2011/Contracts">
  <ErrorCode>-2147220891</ErrorCode>
  <ErrorDetails xmlns:d2p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic">
    <KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
      <d2p1:key>OperationStatus</d2p1:key>
      <d2p1:value xmlns:d4p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d4p1:string">0</d2p1:value>
    </KeyValuePairOfstringanyType>
  </ErrorDetails>
  <Message>Service not available, closing transmission channel. The server response was: 4.3.2 Service not active</Message>
  <Timestamp>2015-04-21T15:31:20.3902191Z</Timestamp>
  <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
  <TraceText>
```

Any idea what may be causing this?

Everything is in a try/catch with the exception of the following code:

```
IPluginExecutionContext context = (IPluginExecutionContext)serviceprovider.GetService(typeof(IPluginExecutionContext));
```

Comment: Is the Catch catching an exception (the one displayed)? or is the exception you've provided displayed on the client when the plugin is executed?

What is the plugin doing? Is it calling an external service? 

Doing an initial search, this error seems to happen in relation to sending an SMTP mail... could be an authentication issue..?

Comment: The catch is catching the exception and you're right the plugin is sending an email so this is an issue with SMTP.